# Using DataProvider on different package .

Tags: android, widget, android-manifest, provider, dataprovider

this is my manifest :

```
<provider
    android:name="DataProvider"
    android:authorities="com.LiveResults.zizo_apps.widget.provider" />
```

but i get this error :

```
Unable to get provider com.LiveResults.zizo_apps.DataProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
 "com.LiveResults.zizo_apps.DataProvider"
```

why is he looking for the class in

com.LiveResults.zizo_apps
instead of 
com.LiveResults.zizo_apps.**widget**

as i wrote in the manifest ?

Comment: post your full manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
android:name="DataProvider"
```

to

```
android:name=".widget.DataProvider"
```